# Check if dom elements with data attribute id then update those elements data attributes

Tags: javascript, signalr, attr

I have a SignalR messagingHub which checks if users are online or not.

Once I identify the id and status of the connected users then I need to update any dom elements which contains data attributes with user ID and update their status.

Basically, I need to show on the website a different class to each dom elements to show which user is online and which one is not.

This is my initial attempt:

```
chatMessagingHub.on('updateUserOnlineStatus', function (userId, isOnline) {

   var status = (isOnline) ? 'online' : 'offline';

   console.log('userid: ' + userId + ' status: ' + status);

   // Check the user id matches any dom elements with a data-attr userid
   if($('[data-userId]') == userId) {

      // Update the selected dom elements data-status attributes
      $(this).attr('[data-status]', isOnline);

      // Detect the change and update the class of the dom element
      $(this).on('change', function() {

         // Check the value of the data-status parameter to add class
         if($(this).attr('data-status') == 'offline') {

            $(this).removeClass('online');

         } else {

            $(this).addClass('online');

         }
      });
   }
});
```

Comment: Just add $(this).trigger('change');

Comment: is $(this) referred to the chatMessagingHub??

Comment: I want to target $(this) as the dom element that has a matching attr userid

Comment: read more here https://api.jquery.com/find/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cant figure out why you re using the change event, anyway remove the first if and use a selector like the example. The IF dont create an isolated scope like a function so you cant use `$(this)` as the selected dom elements

```js
$(function() {
  var isOnline = true;
  var userid = 1;
  var status = (isOnline) ? 'online' : 'offline';
  var elem = $("[data-userid=" + userid + "]");
  elem.attr("data-status", isOnline);
  if (status === "offline")
    elem.removeClass("online")
  else
    elem.addClass("online");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span data-userid="1">hello!</span>
<span data-userid="2">hello!</span>
<span data-userid="1">hello!</span>
<span data-userid="4">hello!</span>
```